# Variable project configuration is bound to in groovy axis plugin for jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a multi-configuration build for which I'd like essentally one build to be run for each file matching `foo/*/bar/*.xml`. I figured the GroovyAxis Plugin would be a nice fit, but I cannot find any documentation on how the build configuration can be accessed from within the script, so I cannot read the workspace-directory from anywhere.

Running something like `return new File('.').listFiles().collect{it.toString()}` returns all files within the root directory of the server.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It took a while to figure this out, but here is a solution. Note that since the Groovy script runs on the master, you must use FilePath to access the files on the slave.

```
import hudson.FilePath

def workspace = context?.build?.workspace

if (null == workspace) {
    return ['noworkspace'] // avoid returning 'default' so the user has a chance of figuring out what went wrong
}

def configDir = workspace.toString() + '/openpower/configs/'

def dir = new FilePath(workspace.channel, configDir)

def files = []
dir.list().each {
    def name = it.getName()
    if (name.endsWith('_defconfig')) {
        files << name.replace('_defconfig', '')
    }
}

return files
```